# Reactjs Child Component

Tags: reactjs

I have a doubt with hierarchy in react.

My Main.js has 2 articles as following:

```
        <article className="angel__flow">
          {steps.map((step, index) => {
            if (procedures[step]){
              return (
                <Flow
                  key={`${index}-${step}`}
                  index={index}
                  opened={currentStepIndex === index}
                  procedure={procedures[step]}
                />
              );
            } else return "";
          })}
        </article>
        <article className="angel__steps">
          {steps.map((step, index) => {
            if (procedures[step]){
              return (
                <Steps
                  key={`${index}-${step}`}
                  index={index}
                  opened={currentStepIndex === index}
                  procedure={procedures[step]}
                  commandSender={sendViewerMessage}
                />
              );
            } else return "";
          })}
        </article>
```

Each article has a map, and for each item, it calls a function. The first one calls the Flow function and the second one calls the Steps function.

My Flow function is the following:

```
function Flow({ index, opened, procedure }) {

  const { t, i18n } = useTranslation();
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

  useEffect(()=>{
    setShow(opened)
  },[opened])

  return (
    <a onClick={() => setShow(!show)} className={`angel__flow__button ${show ? "active" : ""}`}>     
      {t(procedure.title[i18n.language])}
      <span class="angel__flow__button__number">{index+1}</span>  
    </a>
  );
}
```

And my Steps function is the following:

```
function Steps({ index, opened, procedure, commandSender }) {

  const { i18n } = useTranslation();
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState([]);

  function clickHandler(command, index, key, procedure) {
     if (!isSelected(key)) commandSender(`${command}|${index}|${procedure.id}|${key}`)

    if (isSelected(key)) setSelected(selected.filter(s => s !== key))
    else setSelected([...selected, (key)])
  }

  function isSelected(key) {
    return selected.includes(key);
  }

  return (
    <>
      { opened && (
        <>
          {procedure.guide &&
            map(procedure.guide, (value, key) => (
              <a
                key={key}
                className={`angel__steps__button blue ${isSelected(key) ? "active" : ""}`}
                onClick={() => clickHandler('GUIDE', index, key, procedure)}
              >
                {value[i18n.language]}
              </a>
            ))
          }
          <hr />
          {procedure.error &&
            map(procedure.error, (value, key) => (
              <a
                key={key}
                className={`angel__steps__button red ${isSelected(key) ? "active" : ""}`}
                onClick={() => clickHandler('ERROR', index, key, procedure)}
              >
                {value[i18n.language]}
              </a>
            ))
          }
          {procedure.success &&
            map(procedure.success, (value, key) => (
              <a
                key={key}
                className={`angel__steps__button green ${isSelected(key) ? "active" : ""}`}
                onClick={() => clickHandler('SUCCESS', index, key, procedure)}
              >
                {value[i18n.language]}
              </a>
            ))
          }
        </>
      )}
    </>
  );
}
```

What I have to do is: When I click an A tag in the Flow function, it has to open the Steps of that tag.

So, I dont know what I have to do. Maybe send back to my Main function a flag that says that I clicked that tag, so, my Steps function will have it's tag opened.
Can you guys help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

pass in a click handler to `Flow` within `Main.js`:

```
<Flow setCurrentStepHandler={(i) => this.setState({currentStepIndex: this.state.currentStepIndex === i ? null : i})}/>
```

And in `Flow`:

```
<a onClick={() => {
  setShow(!show)
  setCurrentStepHandler(index)
}}
```

That way when `currentStepIndex` is updated, it will pass as a prop to `<Steps .../>`

Comment: Do I have to implement this setCurrentStepHandler function in Main.js? And do I have to pass any other thing to the Steps function?

Comment: I'm sorry, I get really confused with hierarchy in React.

Comment: I'm getting this error now: TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined

Comment: @afr oh if it's a functional component then do `useState` in Main.js, there are other ways to do the `setCurrentStepHandler`, but yeah the version I was talking about is implemented in Main.js